# How to Extract Icons from Executable File in Linux

Tags: linux, debian, executable, icons, launcher

I'm not talking about a Windows EXE. I mean an actual Linux executable file.

At first, I've been wondering whether Linux executables even have embedded icons, and it seems as though they do, because there are programs for which I've never found the icons on my system (I might just be blind, and they were actually hidden somewhere I've never fell upon.)

If this is possible, it would also be great if there were a way of specifying that I want the embedded icon of this or that executable in the "Icon=" statement in my desktop launchers (.desktop) without actually extracting it to a separate file.

I'm running Debian GNU/Linux Bullseye Stable.

Comment: I guess that with "icons" you mean 'launchers', i.e. `files.desktop` . ..... Please see `/usr/share/applications/` ........ "Command line programs", e.g. `ls` etc. etc.: No icons / launchers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A program's icons can be found inside their package source files (not in the executable binary).

Icons for programs that have been installed should be in `/usr/share/icons`.

Comment: Down voted because this answer doesn't answer the question asked.